# PHP 'db2_prepare failed' error

Tags: php, db2

I'm using PHP with IBMi that uses db2. I have store procedure that in a testProcedure.php code is below:

```
                // Prepare Stored Procedure call //
                $proc = 'CALL WLKLIB.DSH3518SQ(?,?,?)';
                $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $proc) or die("db2_prepare failed         " . db2_stmt_error(). " and " .db2_stmt_errormsg());
                db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, 'inCuCode', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
                db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, 'inProdCode', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
                db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, 'inBuyNum', DB2_PARAM_IN,DB2_CHAR);
                db2_execute($stmt);
                while (db2_fetch_row($stmt)) {
                    $Fld1  = db2_result($stmt, 0);
                    $Fld2 =  db2_result($stmt, 1);
                    $Fld3 =  db2_result($stmt, 2);
                    $Fld4 =  db2_result($stmt, 3);
                    $Fld5 =  db2_result($stmt, 4);
                    $Fld6 =  db2_result($stmt, 5);
                    $Fld7 =  db2_result($stmt, 6);
                    $Fld8 =  db2_result($stmt, 7);
                    $Fld9 =  db2_result($stmt, 8);
                    $Fld10 =  db2_result($stmt, 9);
                    $Fld11 =  db2_result($stmt, 10);
                    $Fld12 =  db2_result($stmt, 11);
                    $Fld13 =  db2_result($stmt, 12);
                    ?>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld1;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld2;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld3;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld4;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld5;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld6;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld7;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld8;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld9;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld10;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld11;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld12;?> </p>
                            <p><?php echo $Fld13;?> </p>
                      <?php }?>
```

When this file is execute it runs fine and displays the data, but when it is incorporated with my other code give an error saying "db2_prepare failed" and its the same code i'm using both places can you please me in solve this.
p.s the database connect in reference at the top.

Comment: "db2_prepare failed" is _your_ error message; post the DB2 error code and message.

Comment: this is exactly what it displays: 'db2_prepare failed and' i figured its coming from this: `$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $proc) or die("db2_prepare failed " . db2_stmt_error(). " and " .db2_stmt_errormsg());`

Comment: If you know what fails - what's the question then. We don't know what your `db2_prepare()` does.

Comment: **db2_prepare()** creates a prepared SQL statement which can include 0 or more parameter markers (? characters) representing parameters for input, output, or input/output. You can pass parameters to the prepared statement using db2_bind_param(), or for input values only, as an array passed to db2_execute().

Comment: Its says that **db2_prepare failed**, i think its coming from **$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $proc) or die("db2_prepare failed " . db2_stmt_error(). " and " .db2_stmt_errormsg());** i'm not sure just an assumption, but i don't know why its failing that's the help i need to find the source of the failure, please.